# Will setting a file's modification time to the future with touch() work accross the board?

Tags: php

I have a caching class that has a flat file driver, meaning you can cache arbitrary data to a flat file using a key and expiration time, then retrieve this data using the same key.

Expire duration must be set with the setCache method in order to work with other drivers (as opposed to having an expiration duration argument on the getCache method, even though this would make determining whether the cache has expired much easier, as I could just compare it to the files last modification time).

Currently I prepend a timestamp (+ expire duration) to the beginning of the file. When a user tries to getCache related to that file, the method opens the file and strips off the first line to get this timestamp. It then uses that timestamp to figure out whether or not that cache has expired. This is not very efficient obviously.

I recently came accross a PHP function touch(), which allows me to set a file's last modification time to an arbitrary value. This sounds awesome because it would allow me to (instead of the above mentioned method of figuring out if the cache has expired), set the file's last modification time to some point in the future. I can then check this time to see if the cache has expired yet.

I really REALLY want to be able to use this. My application is distributed however, and since this function works with the environment, I am not sure if I should trust this function to work as expected accross the board on different systems. Does anyone have any information or resources about the compatability of this function?

Comment: interesting problem! but why do you need to set the last modification time to some time in the future? why won't setting it to "now", and then compare the last modification time to a time in the past (more precise, now minus lifespan of cache) work?

Comment: @davogotland I would love to. The problem is, I won't know what the expire duration is at the time of getting the cache, only at the time of setting the cache. This is in order to keep the same interface as the other drivers, as well as for a few usability reasons.

Comment: @davogotland I modified the question to make more clear my current method, which actually adds the expire duration to the timestamp before saving it inside the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest issue you are going to run into here is permissions.  If the user your php script (actually its apache) creates the file, he will own the file and be able to make changes as desired.  This will only work assuming that the apache user has the permissions to create that file inside the folder ( check the directory permissions).

You can also create the file your self and set the owner to be the user that apache runs php scripts as (can be found in the httpd.conf file)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php -- documentation for touch

http://drupal.org/node/34023  --describes the exact situation you are running into and goes more into permissions.

http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap29sec245.html -- talks about modifying the httpd.conf file

Comment: @jacx seeing as php creates the cache files to begin with, I don't forsee problems with permissions.

Comment: @dqhendricks you will run into problems if you don't have the right permissions set for the folder you are trying to create in.  I did some more digging and found that touch is supported across Windows, Unix and Mac sooooo as long as your permissions are set you should be fine to do this.